# How do I iterate over a JSON file in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and for the life of me cannot figure this out.

I have a JSON file (Fontawesome icons):

```
{
  "icons": [
    {
      "name": "Glass",
      "id": "glass",
      "unicode": "f000",
      "created": 1,
      "filter": [
        "martini",
        "drink",
        "bar",
        "alcohol",
        "liquor"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "Web Application Icons"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Music",
      "id": "music",
      "unicode": "f001",
      "created": 1,
      "filter": [
        "note",
        "sound"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "Web Application Icons"
      ]
    },
    // etc
```

To start with I just want to return the name of each icon.

I've been trying to follow various tutorials and have:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import iconList from './services/iconList';

export default class App extends PureComponent {

  render() {
      const items = iconList.map(data=>{
        return(
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>{data.name}</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          )
      })

    return items;
  }
}
```

But I get the error: `.map is not a function`.

I'm not sure what I can do differently. Each tutorial I see seems to use the map function. Is there a better/different way?

Comment: Have you tried `iconList.icons.map(...`

Comment: Also, have you tried console logging `iconList`?  Is it an object, or a string?

Comment: @keikai yep, that's it. Want to make that an answer?

Comment: is `iconList` the name fo the JSON file? Try `iconList.icons.map(icon => ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
const items = iconList.icons.map(data=>{
```

Your data is an object with an icons property in it. You can also destructure your iconList when you import:

```
import {icons as iconList } from './services/iconList';
```